# Login form autofill, in an iframe, in the android browser does not work

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, iframe, autofill

I'm working on a web site that runs in a single document (no real page loads after the first, its all ajax) that you must log in to view. The front page's log in form autofills exactly as you would expect.

The problem is when I load the login form in an iframe. On most browsers it autofills with the same info as the front page and works perfectly. But in the android browser it does not autofill the form at all.

I guess my question is, is there a way to make it function properly in the android browser without just autofilling it server side in the html?

Heres the form's html:

```
<form method="POST" id="login_form" class="disable_on_submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
    <div class="row first">
        <label for="username">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Email Address..." />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password..." />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="awesome" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I couldn't find a direct fix to this issue, I however did come up with a bit of a hack.

First you add a copy of your login form to your actual document, not the iframe:

```
this.fake_form = $('<form method="POST" id="login_form" autocomplete="on"><input type="email" name="username" id="username" /><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></form>');
$(document.body).append(this.fake_form);
this.fake_form.hide();
```

Then you poll your fake form for auto filled data. Being that its hidden, you know the user didn't enter anything.

```
function check_fake_form()
{
    var real_form = this.iframe.contents().find('body #whiteboard');
    var real_u = real_form.find('#username');
    var real_p = real_form.find('#password');

    //if the real form has any values, we're done
    if (real_u.val().trim() != '' || real_p.val().trim()) {
        return;
    }

    var fake_u = this.fake_form.find('#username').val().trim();
    var fake_p = this.fake_form.find('#password').val().trim();

    //if the fake form has values, put them in the real form and quit
    if (fake_u != '' || fake_p != '') {
        real_u.val(fake_u);
        real_p.val(fake_p);

        return;
    }

    //check again in a short time
    setTimeout(check_fake_form, 50);
}
```

This appears to work flawlessly in the version of android that wasn't working, and it does not interfere with browsers that work on their own.